# How many barons did Magna Carta apply to?

Tags: middle-ages, england, civil-rights

How many barons had their rights improved by [Magna Carta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magna_Carta) when it was signed in 1215?

And how did this number evolve later?

The supervising council consisted of 25 barons, but I presume more barons could have been affected.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Quick google search suggests that we don't have a  precise count of the number of barons, but [One historian has suggested that there were about twelve earls in England, and between 100 and 150 barons.](http://ipamagnacarta.org.au/the-magna-carta-barons/).  How many of those had their rights improved is a more difficult question. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_baronies_in_the_Peerage_of_England) enumerates the barons in 1294; that might serve as a starting point for research.

Comment: The original agreement kind of fell apart immediately so in practice the number may as well be zero.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace thank you! Is it really this basic though - there are other titles, such as dukes and counts, probably this was applied, at least to some extent, to the sons and family members, etc.?